# Jackson convertValue does not use JavaTimeModule

Tags: java, json, jackson

If I make a POJO class and convert the whole objects to Json using the `mapper.writeValueAsString()` method, or let Spring handle the conversion, the `JavaTimeModule` is used appropriately and If my POJO had an `OffsetDateTime` in it, it will get converted to a string like `2018-10-16T13:49:34.564748+02:00`.

For some scenarios, I need to use the mapper's `T convertValue(Object fromValue, Class<T> toValueType)` method and build an `ObjectNode` by hand. The method does not convert the `OffsetDateTime` objects the same way as the `writeValueAsString`.

I construct my Jackson mapper like this:

```
ObjectMapper defaultMapperObj = new ObjectMapper();
defaultMapperObj.registerModule(new GuavaModule());
defaultMapperObj.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
defaultMapperObj.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
defaultMapperObj.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

Using the mapper, I can easily convert even Lists to their Json strings:

```
mapper.convertValue(
        Arrays.asList(1,2,23), JsonNode.class
)
```

Results in:

```
ArrayNode: [1,2,23]
```

But If I call this:

```
mappper.convertValue(OffsetDateTime.now(), JsonNode.class)
```

I get a `DecimalNode`: `1542287917.2141993`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`JavaTimeModule`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-datatype-jsr310/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/JavaTimeModule.html) documentation:

> Most `java.time` types are serialized as numbers (integers or decimals as appropriate) if the `SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS` feature is enabled, and otherwise are serialized in standard ISO-8601 string representation. [...]

So, to achieve the desired result, disable the [`SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationFeature.html#WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS) feature in your [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) instance:

```java
mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
```